# Why does the the :last-child selector only selects the "lastest child"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've tried it a few times, and each time the next thing happens:
When I use the `:last-child` selector, it only selects the very last child of the document, while the `:first-child` selector selects **all** the first children of the document. Can someone explain me why? 
Examples:

**:first-child**

```
<style>
p:first-child {background: pink;}
</style>
<body>
<p> This is the first child of the body so the background color is pink </p>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<div>
<p> This is the first child of the div so the background color is also pink </p>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
</div> 
</body>
```

**:last-child**

```
<style>
p:last-child {background: pink;}
</style>
<body>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<p> I expect that this will have a pink background but it won't :( Why? </p>

<div>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<p> This is some text in a paragraph </p>
<p> This is the last child of div and only this paragraph has a pink background </p>
</div> 
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> When I use the `:last-child` selector, it only selects the very last child of the document, while the `:first-child` selector selects **all** the first children of the document.

That's not true. They both select **all** the last and first children of their parents within the document respectively. You have either misunderstood the meaning of "last child" and "first child", or misinterpreted the structure of your page.

`p:first-child` matches two elements here because the first child of `div` *and* the first child of `body` are both `p` elements.

`p:last-child` only matches one element because the last child of your `div` is a `p`, but the last child of `body` is **that `div`**, not a `p`.

Indenting your HTML a bit will make this clearer:

```
<body>
  <p></p>   <!-- First child of body is p -->
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div>     <!-- Last child of body is div -->
    <p></p> <!-- First child of div is p -->
    <p></p>
    <p></p> <!-- Last child of div is p -->
  </div> 
</body>
```

As mentioned, you were probably looking to select the first and last `p` elements, in which case you should use `p:first-of-type` and `p:last-of-type` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`p:last-child` selects `p` elements that are the last child of its parent therefore it is not followed by any sibling elements. `<p> I expect that this will have a pink background but it won't :( Why? </p>` is followed by a `div` which is the last child not its previous sibling the `p`.

I think what you want is the [`:last-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo) pseudo-class. `p:last-of-type {background: pink;}` will select the elements you want.